# create google cloud pub/sub for android subscriptions notifications

Tags: c#, flutter, google-cloud-platform, android-billing

I am totally lost in this point I have finished my subscriptions payment from android application and I need to listen for any subscription on my own backend server to give subscriber the service, but I don't know how to make this happen in proper way, if any one had experience in this point please help .

I haven't find any thing useful in **google documentation or YouTube** .

thanks

I need step by step to make it work.

Comment: You can use https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter. Otherwise, you should have a backend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to enable PUB/SUB API in your project; check this [quick guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-console#before-you-begin) and also ensure that you have selected Android Management API is enabled.
2. Once you have enabled the API you need to create a topic which can publish notifications. You can do it manually in GCP console and by using Pub/Sub [topic method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/create.)
3. Now you need to create a subscription which captures the stream of messages published. check [create subscription method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create).
4. Grant Android device policy and you cand do them manually from console or by Pub/Sub; check [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#api).
5. You need to call enterprises.patch to specify the below parameters

pubsubTopic: projects/{project}/topics{topic}.
enableNotificationTypes: ENROLLMENT, STATUS_REPORT and COMMAND.

6. You can use Pub/Sub API to get [notifications](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber).